# How to create a new user with home directory in a different parition

Tags: permissions, home-directory, adduser

i am trying to add a new user to my system (ubuntu 19.10) from console with a home directory in a separate partition but it seems i cannot do it properly:

My default user is 'gep' and the designated new user's home directory should be under media/gep/work 
(`/dev/sdd1 on /media/gep/work type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uhelper=udisks2)`

```
gep@desk:/media/gep/work$ ls -lah
total 8,0K
drwxrwxrwx  2 gep gep  4,0K Μαΐ   6 20:44 .
drwxr-x---+ 3 gep root 4,0K Μαΐ   6 20:13 ..
```

Adding a new user 'ekt':

```
 gep@desk ~> sudo useradd -m -d /media/gep/work/ekt ekt
 [sudo] password for gep: 
 gep@desk ~> sudo passwd ekt
 New password: 
 Retype new password: 
 passwd: password updated successfully
```

Checking ekt's home permissions:

```
 gep@desk ~> ls -lah /media/gep/work/
 total 12K
 drwxrwxrwx  3 gep gep  4,0K Μαΐ   6 20:54 ./
 drwxr-x---+ 3 gep root 4,0K Μαΐ   6 20:13 ../
 drwxr-xr-x  2 ekt ekt  4,0K Μαΐ   6 20:54 ekt/

 gep@desk ~> ls -lah /media/gep/work/ekt/
 total 20K
 drwxr-xr-x 2 ekt ekt 4,0K Μαΐ   6 20:54 ./
 drwxrwxrwx 3 gep gep 4,0K Μαΐ   6 20:54 ../
 -rw-r--r-- 1 ekt ekt  220 Μαΐ   5  2019 .bash_logout
 -rw-r--r-- 1 ekt ekt 3,7K Μαΐ   5  2019 .bashrc
 -rw-r--r-- 1 ekt ekt  807 Μαΐ   5  2019 .profile
```

Trying to login to new user:

```
 gep@desk ~> su --login ekt
 Password: 
 su: warning: cannot change directory to /media/gep/work/ekt: Permission denied
 $
```

Trying to change permission again:

```
$ sudo chown -R ekt:ekt /media/gep/work/ekt
[sudo] password for ekt: 
ekt is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

I also tried to change owners, permissions etc. but after so many hours i think i am doing the same things all the time. Any help much appreciated:)

update:
Removed the extra ACL permissions with `setfacl -b /media/gep/` but it didn't fix it.

```
gep@desk /> ls -lah /media/gep/
total 12K
drwx------ 3 gep  root 4,0K Μαΐ   6 20:13 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4,0K Οκτ  30  2019 ../
drwxrwxrwx 3 gep  gep  4,0K Μαΐ   6 21:25 work/
```

update x2:
for some reason, it seems that the default settings when i formatted the disk from the gui application 'disks', didn't add an entry to fstab... After i added it manually, it worked and i finally managed to switch users.

Comment: It looks like `/media/gep/` has some kind of alternate access control or ACL set on it - see for example [File Permissions mode ending in @ or +](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92071/file-permissions-mode-ending-in-or)

Comment: deleted and added the user again from scratch after i removed the acl `setfacl -b /media/gep/`. Again same result ( i dont see any extra '+' when i ls the directory)

Comment: What type of filesystem is on `/media`, and how is it mounted?

Comment: a newly formatted ext4 partition which i normally use to cp/mv files/directories without problems. `/dev/sdd1 on /media/gep/work type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uhelper=udisks2)
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next I've done without any issues using 20.04 Virtualbox VM by adding additional virtual disk:
[image]

- `$ sudo fdisk /dev/sdb`
- `n`, `p`, `default 1`, `default 2048`, `default 20971519`, `Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux' and of size 10 GiB.`, `w` - write changes to disk
- `$ sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1`
- `$ sudo mkdir /media/gep`
- `$ sudo blkid` to get `/dev/sdb1` device's UUID:
  `/dev/sdb1: UUID="cca82d89-1c50-4dce-a241-a9c0421464ca" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="3191c204-01"`
- Created the next record in `/etc/fstab` using the UUID:

  ```
  UUID=cca82d89-1c50-4dce-a241-a9c0421464ca /media/gep      ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
  ```
- `$ sudo mount /media/gep`
- `$ sudo adduser test --home /media/gep/test`
- `$ su - test`
- `$ echo $HOME
  /media/gep/test`
- `$ pwd
  /media/gep/test`

Comment: thank you.. I noticed that the automated process of formatting a partition in ubuntu (from 'disks' gui) does not add an entry in fstab for some reason. After i added it myself it worked.

Comment: You are welcome:)